# Ubuntu Installation: Reinstalling Ubuntu and keep files from previous installation

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade

I'm new to Ask Ubuntu, apologies if I'm not specific enough.

I had Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my hp laptop. I attempted to update my distro to 16.04 via command line using this command; "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade". All seemed good, I rebooted my machine so that the changes could take effect. When my laptop had rebooted back into Ubuntu, all that displayed was a black dull screen. I pressed the master terminal keys, it asked for my login and password, but each time I pressed a key, the cursor would just move up, down, left and right all over the place, when I pressed enter, a new line would appear below that looks like something written in Japanese or something.

I think what's happened is the distro update has only partly installed 16.04, so the installation and drivers are just completely screwed. I've attempted to install 16.04 via usb stick where I have been welcomed by a "Upgrade ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04" message on the installation menu, which is a total relief, what I'm wanting to know is, is there a way I can upgrade 14.04 to 16.04 and not loose any of the files I've got inside my 14.04 installation? Any help would be appreciated hugely, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try and be safe. You don't want to loose any of your data. Try this...

Boot the computer.

If the GRUB menu doesn't normally automatically appear for you, hold down the LEFT SHIFT KEY at boot time.

Choose ADVANCED OPTIONS from the GRUB menu, and select the prior kernel, and **see if you can boot properly to 14.04**.

**If you can boot into 14.04**, backup your important files to an external disk or USB flash drive.

Then bring up Software Updater and try the 16.04 upgrade again.

Let us know how you do. Cheers, Al

Comment: Awesome, I'll do exactly that and let you know how that goes. Cheers, Josh

Comment: I tried that, when I get to the terminal I tried entering "startx", but it just said "bin/sh: startx not found", I also tried entering "sudo service lightdm start" and I get the error message "Sudo: not found". Complete boot error man.

Comment: Your last comment wasn't quite clear on what happened. Were you not able to fully boot into your old 14.04? Ok, next try. Do you have an external hard disk or USB flash drive available to backup your important files? If so, boot Ubuntu from a DVD or USB stick, and get your files backed up first. Then, **preferably from a Ubuntu DVD that you burned from the .iso file**, reinstall Ubuntu. I don't remember the exact dialog, but if you install Ubuntu into the same partition as the original, it'll ask if you wish to retain the /home directory that it finds there. Cheers, Al

Comment: Sorry, no I was not able to fully boot into my old 14.04. Yeah that's what I did, I've stuck my most important files onto a 500mb pen, I'm gonna buy an external hard drive to back up the rest. Ahh right, ok man I'll check that out.

Comment: Cheers for the help, Ubuntu 16.04 is installed and working correctly now. On the partition table during installation I clicked on the partition where ubuntu 14.04 was installed and set its type to ext4 and the set the mount point to "/". So now Ubuntu 16.04 is installed and I haven't lost all of my files that I had on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Josh... good news! Vote on my answer, if you can. Cheers, Al

Comment: Can't atm man, my rep isn't at 15 yet, when it is I'll up vote it. Cheers for help dude.

Answer (score -1):

It should keep it automaticlly if not then make a new partition for Ubuntu 16.04 to be installed on and once installed just mount the Ubuntu 14.04 partition to the new Ubuntu install.

Comment: So, O.P. should just give up?

Comment: Ok, I'll read more into making partitions and give it a go. Cheers.

Comment: Also I recommend for the format type unless you want to view your linux partition on windows use the ext4 type use ntfs if you want to see your linux partition on windows (I am not sure on ntfs though)

Comment: See the problem is, my laptop already is partitioned to hell, when I plug in my usb pen it gives me the option to upgrade ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, which is what I want to do, but I get error messages when I click to install and stuff

Comment: Put the errors in your question so we can further see what you are experiencing

Comment: Its ok man I think I've figured it out now, cheers for your help.